# My Bootstrap Datepicker style conflicts with my table style

Tags: html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a table that I just recently edited to have a sticky header with scrollable. However, when I added that change it also affected my Datepicker. Is there a way to bypass this? Or separate them?

Here is the code I added for the table sticky header with scrollable:

```
thead:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar>thead), tbody:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody) {
display: block;
}
.table-container {
    height: 10rem;
}
td:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
}
table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 39.6rem;
    width: 100%;
}

thead:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) {
    /*       head takes the height it requires, 
    and it's not scaled when table is resized */
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: calc(100% - 0.9em);
}

table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) tbody:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody) {
    /*  body takes all the remaining available space */
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

    table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) tbody:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody) tr:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar>tr) {
        width: 100%;
    }

    table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) thead:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar), table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) tbody:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody) tr:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar>tr) {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
tbody:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
   
}
```

Code for the datepicker

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row marginDateStart">
        <label for="StartDate" class="labelmargin">Start Date:</label>
        <input id="datepicker1" class="datepicker" name="datepicker1" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
        <script>
            $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
                uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
                format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
                todayHighlight: true
            });
        </script>

    </div>
```

Libraries I used

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If you check the attached pictures, the first one is with the table fix I made. It conflicts with my datepicker and on the second picture is the datepicker without conflict because I didn't add the table fix I made.

[Datpicker with the table fix i made][1]

[Datepicker without the table fix i made][2]

LATEST UPDATE:
After some troubleshooting above CSS snippet code now works and doesn't conflict with datepicker. The key is the :not(.ui-datepicker-calendar>thead) format for extra granulanity

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try excluding the datepicker css classes in your css.

```
table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 39.6rem;
    width: 100%;
}
table > :not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) tbody {
    height: 100px;  Just for the demo          
    overflow-y: auto;  Trigger vertical scroll    
    overflow-x: hidden;  Hide the horizontal scroll 
}
/* add more for other affected css rules */
```

more info on :not https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: i tried to add it on the table tag and got some minor results. do i need to add it also on the others like thead etc? sorry im very new to css styling.

Comment: yes ideally you want to also add it to others like thead, but after reviewing the rendered html from the date picker here is the class you want to use for the table css rule. table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar). See of that helps. If it's still interfering with your thead, tbody, etc. Something like thead:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar>thead) if you need that extra granularity.

Comment: i added an update on my code above it appears the only thing left is the size of the Datepicker which i cannot find what to edit in the inspect in F12.

Comment: I would think i need to lessen some in the css but dont know which? @RobSmitha

Comment: Ok i managed to troubleshoot it with trial and error and posted the correct answer above thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is: give class names to your custom tables and use datepicker's table id for editing datepicker tables.

See Snippet below:

```js
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
  uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
  format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
  todayHighlight: true
});
$("#datepicker1").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

```css
/*Styles for datepicker*/

#ui-datepicker-div thead {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

/*Styles for other tables*/
.otherTables{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="d-flex flex-row marginDateStart">
        <label for="StartDate" class="labelmargin">Start Date:</label>
        <input id="datepicker1" class="datepicker" name="datepicker1">
</div>
<table class="otherTables">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: but if i need to edit the tr/th/tbody of "otherTables" do i need to add some classes on them or is it undestood since its under table tag?

Comment: If you need to edit tr/th/tbody of "otherTables", you just access it by using "otherTables tr, otherTables th, otherTables tbody" syntax. It is called "Descendant Selector". The "otherTables" is the outer frame/parent element, and "tr/th/tbody" is the inner frame/child element of "otherTables". Hope it answers you.

Comment: This does get the job done, however it requires all future tables to have the "otherTables" css class added which adds extra work. This is no big deal for learning purposes or for a small site but when a site has many tables, adding the css class becomes cumbersome.